# How does one use lambdas on the mustache.js demo page?

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I have been trying for about an hour to get a lambda to work with the mustache.js [demo](http://mustache.github.io/#demo). Nearly all of the examples online which demonstrate lambdas, do so by declaring the json inline with their js.

I've tried the following JSON:

```
{
  "planet": "The be the name",
  "lambda": "function() {return \"{{planet}}\"}"
}
```

with the following mustache:

```
{{lambda}}
```

.. with no success. Is there a way to use the mustache demo page to demonstrate lambdas?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not. It's not possible to represent a lambda as JSON. Your example is just two strings, one of which happens to be a function if you `eval()` it. This would work:

```
{
    "planet": "World",
    "lambda": function() { return "{{planet}}" }
}
```

... except that it's invalid JSON so it won't :(

Comment: That's what has me confused. It looks like you can only use lambdas if you are defining the JSON within JS. So, it looks like you couldn't use the lambda functionality with an over the wire JSON object, because the JSON would be invalid.

Comment: Yep. That is correct. A common approach is to send data over the wire as JSON, then mix in lambdas via JS before rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like lambdas are not supported on the demo page even though they work using the library normally. Probably an oversight, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Looking at the source from the demo page, the version is shown as "0.2.3-dev" while master branch of mustache.js github is at "0.7.2".

Answer (score 1):

I declare my lambda in my js code. After I've catched the JSON from server and put it in `myVar`, I do something like the following, prior to calling `Mustache.render`:

```
myVar.myLambda = function(text,render) {
    return '<b>'+render(text)+'<b>';
}
```

`render` renders the mustache variable passed in brackets, which is the `text` parameter for the lambda function, and you should pass it in your HTML like this:

```
<div class="blah"><p>The planet is: {{#myLambda}}{{planet}}{{/myLambda}}</p></div>
```